# Unity problem with collision - collision doesn't work after specific collision

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics

I have multiple `GameObject`s in my Scene.

There is some *Package*, player need to collect this. `BoxCollider2D` is attached to them. Here is the configuration :

[image]

Here is the player's configuration:

[image]

Another configuration of player:

[image]

Intentionally placed to `Collider`, so one can detect `body touch` and another `fall over head` of package.

And there is also a walkway. Here is the configuration :

[image]

Every `RigidBody2D` has `Continues` collision detection.

Still it creates problem, first everything is cool as it should be. Later *Player* stops colliding but collides sometimes. Why is that ?

What can be the probable cause?

Here is scene-view :

[image]

Here is some shots :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DoWSG0hlZZb0KIX-oUWI8FPXK5HepppY/view?usp=sharing

**Big File for Stack Overflow - 35MB**

[image]

Here is the project : https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Slicer2D-Unity

Comment: What exactly is it that's it's not doing? Is it that the collisions with the walkway are working but not with the 'package'? If so check that the package is selected as a trigger.

Comment: Are you sure that your Player has a `Rigidbody 2D`? In order for two colliders to collide, at least one needs a rigidbody. You should share the script, which contains the Player's movement

Comment: Yes, I'm sure `Player` has `RigidBody2D`

Comment: Here is the full project : https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Slicer2D-Unity

Comment: Here is the `PlayerMovementController` : https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Slicer2D-Unity/blob/master/Slicer-2D/Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovementController.cs